# losing my data after running print function two times

Tags: c, printing, hashtable, function-pointers

This is my code, I have to code a hash-table with a vector of 10 items where each item is the head to a linked list.

My code is running correctly when I choose option 1 and print the hash-table but with option 2 when I print again my data on the hash-table is lost and all values are NULL.

I think the problem is in the function of print. I tried to redo and use another variable to print the vector but it didn't worked.

**I appreciate any type of help!**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct no{       
    int id;   
    char name;       
    struct no *next;
}no;

void insert(no * vetor, int idInsert, char nameInsert, int pinsert){
    no *newNo = (no*)malloc(sizeof(no));
    newNo->id = idInsert;
    newNo->name = nameInsert;
    newNo->next = NULL;

    if ((vetor[pinsert]).next == NULL){ 
        (vetor[pinsert]).next = newNo;
        return;}
    newNo -> next = (vetor[pinsert].next);
    vetor[pinsert].next = newNo;
    }

void printVetor(no * vetor){
    no * vetoraux = vetor;
    for (int n = 0; n<= 9; n++){
        if(vetoraux[n].next == NULL){
            printf("->[NULL]\n");}
        else{
            do{
                printf("-> [id: %d] ", (vetoraux[n]).next->id);                
                (vetoraux[n]).next = (vetoraux[n]).next -> next;          
            } while ((vetoraux[n]).next != NULL);
            printf("-> [NULL]\n");
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    no vetor[10];
    for (int n = 0; n<= 9; n++){
        (vetor[n]).next = NULL;}
    
    int option;
    do{
        printf("1-insert ints \n2-print hashtable\n5-esc\n");
        scanf("%d", &option);
        switch (option){
        case 1:
            insert(vetor, 10, 'c', 2);
            insert(vetor, 20, 'c', 2);
            insert(vetor, 30, 'c', 3);
            insert(vetor, 40, 'c', 3);
            break;
        case 2:
            printVetor(vetor);
            break;
        case 5:
            printf("End\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid\n");
            break;
        };
    }while(option != 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use the only handle you have to the start of the list to iterate through the list. Make a disposable copy of that and use the disposable copy to print each node's data.

Comment: Why is your print function doing `(vetoraux[n]).next = (vetoraux[n]).next -> next;`? I'd expect a print function to purely print the data, not modify it. You could pass a pointer to const which would result in the compiler preventing you from modifying the parameter accidentally, at least until you use the first `next` member. Btw: I recomment introducing a global constant to specigy the array size in a single place without having to modify every single part of the code using it: `constexpr size_t VetorSize = 10; ... for (size_t n = 0; n < VetorSize; ++n) ...`

Comment: Btw: Why this unecessary case distinction? You don't need to implement a case distinction, if you implement the loop the right way: `void printVetor(no const* vetor) { for (size_t n = 0; n < VetorSize; ++n) { no const* node = &vetor[n]; while (node->next != NULL) { printf("-> [id: %d] ", node->next->id); node = node->next; } printf("-> [NULL]\n"); }}`

Comment: You've defined an array of 10 pointers, each to a linked list, but where are the ten "hash" values supposed to live?